# Easy error handling

Tags: error-handling, rust

I've started using the following `Error` configuration for some simple libraries I've been working on:

```
pub mod err {
    use std::{error, fmt, result};

    macro_rules! from {
        ($t: ty) => {
            impl ::std::convert::From<$t> for Error {
                fn from(e: $t) -> Self {
                    Error::Boxed(e.into())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub enum Error {
        All,
        My,
        Var(Iants),
        Boxed(Box<error::Error + Send + Sync>)
    }

    impl error::Error for Error {
        fn description(&self) -> &str {
            match *self {
                /* ... */
                Error::Boxed(ref e) => { e.description() },
            }
        }
    }

    impl fmt::Display for Error {
        fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
            error::Error::description(self).fmt(f)
        }
    }

    pub type Result<T> = result::Result<T, Error>;

    from!(::std::string::FromUtf8Error);
    from!(::std::str::Utf8Error);
    from!(::std::ffi::NulError);
    /* ... */
}
```

I'm pretty happy with this—it lets me generate my own errors and handle external errors pretty easily.

A couple questions:

Is it bad form to "throw away" the type info like this for the errors I am boxing?

Is there an easier way to do this? For example, I could do away with my `from!` macro and calls if I could do something like:

```
impl<E> From<E> for MyErrorEnum
    where E: ::std::error::Error and E != MyErrorEnum {}
```

I think this would be possible with negative trait bounds (which is not currently available in Rust).

Are there any other issues I'm missing?

Comment: Have you seen [quick-error](https://github.com/tailhook/quick-error)?

Comment: @Shepmaster, no, thanks! That looks super handy.